# How to reference data which is stored in a Table for VBA Code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to run my codes which are stored in a specific field of a table in a text type. 
My table contains below fields:
CodeID as int
RibbonTabID as Nvarchar(50)
ActionButtonCode as ntext
.
I generate a custom ribbon in access and name the id of this button as "B_01".
In my table, I write B_01 in RibbonTabID field and "DoCmd.OpenForm "Loginform", , , , , acDialog" in ActionButtonCode field.
I write this code in VBA to execute the action in the specific field.

```
Public Sub OnActionButton(control As IRibbonControl)
'Callbackname in XML File "onAction"

    Select Case control.id
       Case control.id
        Dim RunAction As String
        Dim dbHadish As DAO.Database
        Dim rstEmployees As DAO.Recordset
        Dim strFirstName As String


        Set dbHadish = CurrentDb
        Set rstEmployees = dbHadish.OpenRecordset("dbo_tblOnActionButton", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

        rstEmployees.MoveFirst
        strFirstName = rstEmployees!ActionCode

        Shell (strFirstName)

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Button " & control.id & " click"
        End Select
End Sub
```

This piece of does not work.
I also use Dlookup as below, but this code also does not work.

```
        Dim RunAction As String
        Set RunAction = DLookup("[ActionCode]", "[dbo_tblOnActionButton]", "[RibbonTabID] = '" & "B_10" & "'")
        Eval (RunAction)
```

Comment: `Set` is only used when you want to store an object into a variable, not just data. So try `RunAction = DLookup("[ActionCode]", "[dbo_tblOnActionButton]", "[RibbonTabID] = '" & "B_10" & "'")` without `Set`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this code is not working.

Comment: What error does it arises?